# Does SOA require a new instance of a webserver for each microservice?

Tags: node.js, express, soa

Let's say I want a simple set of web services off of one domain:

- User authentication
- Projects datastore

Does this mean I would create 2 different databases, with 2 different instances of express/flask/etc, with 2 different servers running on 2 different ports?

Answer (score 1):

In short ***no it does not require it***, however you can do it like that if this is what ***you require***.

Remember microservices allows you to create services in a polyglot fashion. For example you could host the user authentication in C++ and the projects in Java. However most developers feel that hosting every microservice on a different technology is overkill.

Microservices will typically share a persistent storage of some sort i.e. a common SQL/NoSQL database back end. They are typically hosted on the same server as well though they would be in a different process space potentially allowing you to make the services come and go without affecting the whole.

The micro part really refers to the business context and has nothing to do with technical side of things.  So having every service on a separate database and server does not make it a "microservice".

A service that does both employee registration and customer registration is probably not a microservice if one considers that customers and employers are two entities that have life cycles of their own. An employee might be assigned to a customer but they should not share a service context.

Remember there is no right or wrong decisions in this. Just successful and unsuccessful SOA implementations.

Comment: The business context of this design philosophy is not relevant to me, I am namely interested in the following aspects of SOA/microservices:

- How modular it is; easier to debug, create, and destroy a service if needbe
- If one service goes down or experiences an uncaught error, other services still function just fine
- Performance
- Independence

The polyglot approach is interesting but I will likely stick with node as I feel it's more tailored for this approach.

Comment: SOA does not have any technical implementation. Its an architectural approach not a technical one. If you use .net or java or basic is not relevant. You choose the tech and how it is done on the back end. However if solution does not follow SOA principles then its not SOA